# What unary operation on sequences produces the sequence of pairwise sums?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, terminology

Given a sequence $(a, b, c,...)$:

- the partial difference operator produces the sequence $(b-a, c-b, ...)$, and
- the partial summation operator produces the sequence $(a, a+b, a+b+c, ... )$

according to [a section in the Wikipedia page on series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Calculus_and_partial_summation_as_an_operation_on_sequences).

What about the sequence $(a+b, b+c, c+d, ...)$?

Is there a formal name for the operator that produces this one?

Comment: What good is a formal name here?  If you have use for it and you don't know of a formal name, just name it yourself and explain the name and notation.  Also, why bother refering to this as an unary operation?  What is unsatisfactory about using binary operations instead?  With $A=(a,b,c,d,\dots)$, Using $\ell(A)$ as the left-shift operator $\ell(A)=(b,c,d,e,\dots)$ you can have $A+\ell(A)$ is the result you want.

Comment: As for what the formal name might be, I haven't heard a formal name yet for it yet, but I would guess that it is exactly what you would call it... "*pairwise summation*" or something similar

Comment: "What good is a formal name here" -- mostly I'm just curious. I thought it was interesting that there's a formal name for the operators that produce the other two sequences I gave as examples, and was wondering if there was an agreed-upon name for the third. Maybe "pairwise summation" is the closest. Thank you!

Comment: In time series analysis, I have typically seen the "left-shift" operator called the lag operator or backshift operator.